lenovo ideapad 110 starts up twice on Ubuntu 22.04 lts problem
I installed Ubuntu 22.04 lts but it starts up twice. It starts then turns off and starts back on again. How can i solve this problem using Ubuntu terminal. I changed the boot order after sudo gedit /etc/default/grub command, but the laptop still starts up twice.

You mention changing a setting of grub, but what you do mention will not take effect until after next kernel upgrade/removal OR you caused a new grub to be updated yourself; did you update-grub yourself?  (ie. tell it to read your settings & create a new grub used by the boot process)
